# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__' (Worked a week ago?)

Tags: python, tensorflow

[Image: Error Message and Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1W5k.png)

I am working on Google Colab and do not have much experience with Python. The image above has code that is from https://github.com/smousavi05/EQTransformer

The packages that are installed by EQTransformer are:

```
EQTransformer-0.1.59  
SecretStorage-3.3.1  
cryptography-3.4.7  
gast-0.2.2  
h5py-2.10.0  
jeepney-0.6.0  
keras-2.3.1  
keras-applications-1.0.8  
keyring-23.0.1  
pkginfo-1.7.0  
tensorboard-2.0.2  
tensorflow-2.0.0  
tensorflow-estimator-2.0.1  
tqdm-4.48.0
```

I also get an error when running the EQTransformer install

```
ERROR: tensorflow-probability 0.12.1 has requirement gast>=0.3.2, but you'll have gast 0.2.2 which is incompatible.
```

I have tried installing the newer gast but Tensorflow 2.0 requires the older gast.
I have also tried installing tensorflow-probability 0.9.0 to be compatible with 0.2.2 gast but still I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

! pip install tensorflow==1.15.0
! pip uninstall keras-nightly
! pip install keras==2.0.8
like this